# How to install pg_dump 9.3.2 on ubuntu?

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I am trying to install this specific version of pg_dump, but on apt-get I can only download the 9.3.3 version.

I need this to run a dump on a remote 9.3.2 postgres server.

Thanks.

Comment: You should have no problem just using the 9.3.3 binary on the 9.3.2 remote. You only need to match the major version, e.g. both must be 9.3.